# Characteristic function of Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

How do I show that if $X$ is a Bernoulli-r.v. with parameter $p$, then
$$
\varphi_X(u)=E[e^{iuX}]=e^{iu0}(1-p)+e^{iu}p
$$
**Without** using the characteristic function of a binomial-r.v. with parameters n,p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Ee^{iuX }=Ee^{iuX }I_{\{X=0\}}+Ee^{iuX }I_{\{X=1\}}=Ee^{0 }I_{\{X=0\}}+Ee^{iu }I_{\{X=1\}}=P(X=0)+e^{iu}P(X=1)=(1-p)+e^{iu}p$.

Answer (score 2):

We can evaluate the expected value $E[e^{iuX}]$ using the [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). We have that
$$
E[e^{iuX}]=(1-p)e^{iu0}+pe^{iu}=(1-p)+pe^{iu}.
$$